# Expanding Background to 100% of bootstrap 3 .row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I have HTML like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
          <div id="product-spotlight" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
               <div class="product-spotlight-inner">
```

The CSS for `product-spotlight-inner` simply contains a `background-image`.

The problem is, `bootstrap-3` puts padding of `padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px` on the `col`.  So the background image does not extend to the end.  I could put up with it but it looks bad on mobile.

I'm I doing it wrong? is this  a known issue? something else?

**EDIT**:  I am starting to think the `container-fluid` is adding the `15px` (in addition)

**EDIT2**:  I added a new id called `product-spotlight` and gave it 0 padding and that fixed it.  Is that just a hack?

Comment: remove the `padding` from the parent div and add it to 'product-spotlight-inner'

Comment: @KickingLettuce you have just to override the bootstrap style for that  `div` element with _.col_ class as you did, or play with `negative margin` on the left and right as I said in my response.

Comment: looks like you're mess up with css priorities, `#bla` is always higher than `.bla` that makes it work. don't use it if you don't have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sure you can get negative margins to work, though you have to be careful to check for unwanted results at different viewports or layout suprises when you add extra elements to the div.

You could apply the background to the row instead .. nice and simple and no surprises.
http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/rfrzvey1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row product-highlight">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
   <div class="product-spotlight-inner">product highlight div</div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.product-highlight{
    background-color:pink;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try by doing `margin:0 -15px`:

```
.product-spotlight-inner{
    background:url("http://www.ihdwallpapers.me/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Paris-Eiffel-tower-hd-wallpapers.jpg") no-repeat center;
    background-size:cover;
    display:block;
    margin:0 -15px;
    padding:0 15px;
    height:400px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2hcz2wrv/